# Keyboard for night MMO gaming on plasma TV (please advice)

Tags: gaming, wireless, keyboards

I am desperately looking for a keyboard which satisfies my particular playstyle:

Required Features:

1. Wireless (to be used on armchair in front of TV)
2. Illuminated (to play with lights off)
3. Full analog numpad (calculator is used A LOT for trading)
4. Reliable (no sudden lags and missed/duplicate keys - unforgivable in gaming)

Nice-to-haves:

- Slim (it was 'required' before, for typing speed, but I had to sacrifice it to broaden the choices)
- Ability to charge by USB cable while continuing to use
- AA/AAA or other conventional batteries
- mini receiver (for travelling)

So far I have been using **Logitech K800** (so basically looking for better alternative). But there were two issues with it:

- Key scissor mechanisms are very fragile (so now 8 of them are broken beyond repair)
- Illumination turns on either on sensor (and stays on for non-configurable period of about 5 sec) or key press (and then it is possible to configure for how long it is on). Both ways are inconvenient first due to sensor range and second due to the need to press smth.

If I won't find anything I'll have to buy new K800 of course, but it is rather sad surprise that keyboard makers were unable to create anything better for the last 8 years.

Comment: Traditional batteries and USB charging seem mutually exclusive.

Comment: I agree with @JanDorniak, never seen one with both conventional batteries and a built-in charger. By "analog", I'm guessing you mean real buttons, not a non-binary switch?

Comment: I think you'll find it impossible to find a wireless keyboard that meets those reqs.